# Exclude imported configurations from Spring Boot Application in a @SpringWebMvc test

Tags: spring-boot, integration-testing, spring-test, spring-boot-test

I'm working with a multi module spring boot application that imports configurations from other modules.

```
@SpringBootApplication
@Import({
  FooConfiguration.class,
  BarConfiguration.class
})    
public class SpringBootApplication { ... }
```

and would like to write a `@WebMvcTest` for a `@RestController`. Configurations imported in the `SpringBootApplication` class should be disabled when application context loads.

I've already tried to use `@WebMvcTest#excludeAutoConfiguration`, to exclude `SpringBootApplication.cass` itself as well as `@WebMvcTest#excludeFilters` to exclude packages containing configuration classes. None of them worked for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because `FooConfiguration` and `BarConfiguration` are just the normal configuration class but not the auto-configuration class and `excludeAutoConfiguration` only takes effect on the auto-configuration class.

Also `excludeFilters` is the attribute from the `@ComponentScan` , so it will only take effect if the configuration class are detected because of the component scanning but does not work if it is defined explicitly using `@Import`.

One easy way to fix it use `@Profile` to conditionally import those external modules configurations such that they will not be imported if it is running the test.

Something likes:

```java
@SpringBootApplication
@Import(ExternalModuleConfiguration.class)
public class SpringBootApplication { ... }


@Configuration
@Import({FooConfiguration.class, BarConfiguration.class}) 
@Profile("!test")  
public class ExternalModuleConfiguration {
}
```

Then in test, set the active profile to `test` such that `ExternalModuleConfiguration` will not be imported :

```java
@ActiveProfiles("test")
@WebMvcTest
public class BootTest {

}
```

Comment: Hi Ken, great explanation! I like the approach you suggested and will accept it. It will work for 99% of the cases. Due to the complexcity of the imported configs, extracting them into another class has implications and it breaks bean creation order which is even more complex to change or improve. I ended up using simply `@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)` and `MockMvc#standaloneSetup`. It bypass `SpringBootApplication` so I can leave it as is.